# Latex - References are not numbered

Tags: reference, latex, bibtex

I have the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}

\newenvironment{tightcenter}{%
  \setlength\topsep{0pt}
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\include{intro}
\include{stateart}
\include{matmet}
\include{perso}
\section{Conclusion}
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that references are not numbered, all I see is [] for each reference, and when I cite a reference, it is always cited as [0].

I use taxmaker with pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex (x2) + view pdf quick build command.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/dickimaw/dickimaw-minexample.pdf)? Your code leaves out most of your document, including the references in question.

Comment: Oops I'm sorry about that, references were used the classical way. The problem was with the \usepackage{natbib} which messed everything up I don't know why.